# My Attempt at a Pinterest HTML

Tags: html, css

I wrote some html to create blocks of text/images similar to Pinterest. I tried using "float:left" to create 3 columns of tile but the alignment just isn't correct.

http://jsfiddle.net/cme0848/zran44vr/6/

```
.tb-box{
   font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
   width:245px;
   border-radius:5px;
   background-color:#f3f3f5;
   float:left;  
   margin-right:5px;
   text-align:center;
   margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

How can I get my tiles to fill correctly from left-to-right?

~Craig

Answer (score 0):

According to a colleague, this type of styling isn't possible in CSS using today's W3C standards. I'm going to have to change up my code to use jquery.

This basically what I was looking for.
[Simple Jquery Plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/layout/Simple-jQuery-Plugin-To-Create-Pinterest-Style-Grid-Layout-Pinterest-Grid.html). A lightweight and flexible implementation of a pintrest style grid. All I had to do was insert my DIVs inside the  tags within the example HTML they provided.

Comment: Why not have 3 floating columns and then content boxes in each of them?

Comment: I think I would run into problems when I attempted to design the site for responsivness. As the window or screen size grew/shrank I need the "tiles" (content boxes) to move from one column to the other.

Comment: This was basically what I was looking for. A super light weight frame work which would work with my existing design. I've now been successful with this. http://www.jqueryscript.net/layout/Simple-jQuery-Plugin-To-Create-Pinterest-Style-Grid-Layout-Pinterest-Grid.html

Comment: You should update the answer specifying this and adding a short demo. It may be helpful for future readers